# half-bounded subsets of R, either open or closed?

Tags: real-analysis

If there is a set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}: x<y\}$ is it correct to say that this set is open because $y$ is its only boundary point, and is not contained in the set?

Similarly, is it correct to say that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}: x\leq y\}$ is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both correct since in any topological space $X$:

A set $A\subset X$ is open iff $\partial A\cap A=\emptyset$.

A set $F\subset X$ is closed iff $\partial F\subset F$.

In this case $X=\mathbb{R}$, $\partial\{x\in\mathbb{R}: x<y\}=\partial\{x\in\mathbb{R}: x\leq y\}=\{y\}$ and conclusion follows.